# Regular expression pattern

Tags: regex, perl

Regular expressions are one of the things that still escape me.  What I want is simple enough, but I have yet to be able to consistently match.  The text I want to match is `/ssl/checkoutstep1.aspx` regardless of case.

Comment: Your effort so far is appreciated...

Comment: This case seems too simple to use a regex. Just lowercase the string and check for equality.

Comment: The language is standard perl, but the implementation is not for a language but rather an A/B testing interface, so I just need the pattern itself.

Comment: My effort so far has been fruitless. As for this case being to simple, it's not a matter of finding the right tool for the match; it's a matter of being required to use regex.

Comment: jjnguy depending on the language, might have a case insensitive compare.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of the default delimiter `/`, it's easier if you use a non-slash like pipe: `|`

```
if ($string =~ m|/ssl/checkoutstep1\.aspx|i) {
  print 'match';
} else {
  print 'no match';
}
```

I'm assuming you actually need Regex (because you want to learn it, or you are doing a path rewrite, or something).  Your example could easilly be solved with simple case-insensitive indexof or contains.

Answer (score 1):

Since it doesn't look like you really need a regular expression, you should consider eq or [index](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/index.html).

```
if ( lc( $string ) eq '/ssl/checkoutstep1.aspx' ) { ... } ## for exact matches
```

or

```
if ( index( lc( $string ), '/ssl/checkoutstep1.aspx' ) != -1 ) { ... } ## for partial matches
```

This is faster and avoids the confusion of regular expressions. If you insist on regular expressions, agent-j's response is what you want, although I prefer {}.

```
if ( $string =~ m{\Q/ssl/checkoutstep1.aspx\E}i ) { ... } ## the \Q and \E escape the special chars between them
```

Comment: I'm not convinced that it's faster, since `lc` has to make a copy of a (potentially large) string, and `m//i` uses a reasonably quick bitmap-based method to do case-insensitive searches (at least when not in Unicode mode).

Comment: I have benchmarked it before, but that was with an older version of perl. I think the larger the string, the slower the regex (the regex shown, not one with anchors).

Comment: I benchmarked them again and index/eq almost always beat the regex. The only case that it doesn't is when the string is long AND the match is at the very beginning.

Comment: oh, anchor the regex match! `m{^\Q/fixed/string\E\z}i`

Comment: eq is about twice as fast as the anchored regex on my machine, according to my benchmark.